# Puppet: "latest" vs. latest

Tags: puppet

Consider the following code:

```
  $version = 'latest'
  package { 'mypkg':
    ensure => $version;
  }
```

Will this do the same thing as:

```
  package { 'mypkg':
    ensure => latest;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those will do the same thing.

Puppet allows simple strings to be unquoted. `latest` and `"latest"` are equivalent. Passing a variable that holds the same value is also equivalent.

Note that the [style guide](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/style_guide.html#quoting) only suggests using unquoted bare words in limited circumstances. If there's any question at all, it's better to put single-quotes (`'`) around a string.

Comment: As in many Perl-like languages, though, using unquoted strings in this fashion is discouraged, because they could be reserved words in future versions. No, it's not likely in the case of `latest`.

Comment: @FelixFrank: The [style guide](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/style_guide.html#quoting) does seem to explicitly allow bare words for alphanumerics that are not resource names. Many examples in the style guide use unquoted bare word strings for the ensure parameter.

Comment: I admit, I'm not well in touch with the style guide. It's true that `absent` and `present` are so pervasive that it can be safely assumed that they will never become keywords. `latest` on the other hand is only available for the `package` type and possibly not as privileged. It's a good point though.